# Show loading widget while high resolution image is loading

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I have a photo gallery, with high resolution photos. I am using grid to list all the photos. And, it is not the case for network images.

What I want is while photo is not shown, I want to show [spin_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit) while images are loading instead of blank boxes.

Main class:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: MyAppbar(
      centerLogo: true,
    ),
    body: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      mainAxisSpacing: 8,
      crossAxisSpacing: 8,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      childAspectRatio: 1,
      children: mapIndexed(
        galleryItems,
        (index, item) => PhotoItem(
          photoItem: item,
          onTap: () {
            open(context, index);
          },
        ),
      ).toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Each photo item. Class name: **PhotoItem**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    child: Hero(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Image.asset(
          photoItem.assetName,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      tag: photoItem.assetName,
    ),
  );
}
```

I can use cache height to show the images quickly by reducing quality of image. But, in this case I want to load whole image at the little box. I know it will kill phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my experience, always use GridView.builder, more efficiency when lots of items need to be shown. Second always use thumbnail for listing, otherwise you list will be very slow or even crash at the end. Only show original size of picture in detail.

Comment: Yes, i got that point of using thumbnail for listing. +1 for your suggestions and sharing your experience. But, I cannot accept the answer.

Comment: oh, I am so sorry, you can used FadeInImage, put SpinKitRotatingCircle in placeholder and your image in image parameter.

Comment: Okay, let me check.

Comment: Well, , it works but doesn't. ```placeholder``` takes **ImageProvider**, but **SpinKitRotatingCircle** can't be there.

Comment: or can you accept default circular spin? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images

Comment: I think I will be adding ```.gif``` as the package doesn't work for me. Thanks btw.